# Detox giving a false positive on `expect(...)toBeVisible()`

Tags: detox

I'm having some trouble understanding why detox is telling me elements are visible when they are not to the naked eye.

Our application has testIDs attached to basically any element that we would write tests against. [Here is an example of a screen that we would display to the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrsA4.png)

[And this is what it looks like when there is no text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY5im.png)

Detox passes in both scenarios on the visibility of the element.

We did realize that we had a flex in the view that caused the text to wrap incorrectly, but it is concerning that detox tells me the element is visible when it clearly isn't.

I tried updating the visibility threshold to 100 in `toBeVisible` as well as using `getAttributes` and asserting the visible attribute was true.

We could employ visual regression testing but that feels cumbersome and unnecessary, is there something we're missing to resolve this?